# XAMLParseException in C# Application in Break Mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mvvm, visual-studio-2019

Well I am currently programming on a project where I use MovelViewModel and DependencyInjection. Furthermore, I am using a Database.

This is my code which causes the error:

```
 private readonly MusikContext db;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    
    public MainWindow(MusikContext db, IServiceProvider serviceprovider)
    {
        this.db = db
    this.serviceprovider = serviceprovider
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

If I use the code like this:

```
  public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

No error comes up but it opens two MainWindows

Comment: As your code is not XAML, it cannot be the source of the problem. Are there any exception details?

Comment: How do you call the constructor(s) of the MainWindow? Is it WPF application. Share your App.xaml and exception details.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the variable  "this.serviceprovider" to " this.serviceProvider". Error because of a little mistake.